# Ordering based on another model attribute - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models.  Category and Photo.  There are many photos for each category.

I want to order a category object array in such a way that it is ordered by an attribute in the Photo model. Specifically how many times a photo is downloaded.

I am trying to initiate the instance variable with something like

```
@category = Category.active.order('photos.qty_download DESC)
```

I would then use that instance variable to list the categories and how many photos have been downloaded for each category

```
Chicago   45
San Fran   32
Boston    23
etc
```

What expression will work in Rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that your models look something like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Let's also assume:

- each photo has a `qty_download` field as you describe in your
  question
- each category has a `name` field
- the goal is to order the display of categories according to
  the sum of all the `qty_download` for all of the photos in each
  category
- it's okay to exclude entirely categories that have no associated photos

---

With those assumptions, you should be able to write

```
Category.
  joins(:photos).
  group("categories.id, categories.name").
  select("categories.id, categories.name, sum(photos.qty_download) as total_downloads").
  order("total_downloads desc")
```

Note that what will be returned will be "partial" category objects that contain only `id`, `name`, and `total_downloads`. If you want additional category fields, add them to both the `group` and the `select` clauses.

***Update***

Newer versions of Postgres allow a simplification of the query:

```
Category.
  joins(:photos).
  group("categories.id").
  select("categories.*, sum(photos.qty_download) as total_downloads").
  order("total_downloads desc")
```

Note that in recent versions of Postgres, you can simply group by a unique id -- you no longer must group by all attributes that you which to include in your select. So you can now include all the attributes of categories as `categories.*`. I'll leave the original in place as it is (marginally) more efficient and backwards-compatible with older versions of Postgres.

Comment: And in case you want all fields from category, do:

    select("categories.*, SUM(photos.qty_download) AS times_downloaded")

And I think simply grouping by "categories.id" should be sufficient

Comment: At least for Postgres, when you use group, everything in the `select` clause must either appear in the `group by` clause or be an aggregate function, so neither of your suggestions would work. YMMV with other databases.

Comment: are you positive? because i ran the original on mysql but now i'm on a rails project using postgres and the following executes perfectly well from the rails console:


`Model1.limit(1).joins(:model2s).group("#{Model1.table_name}.id").select("#{Model1.table_name}.*, SUM(#{Model2.table_name}.id) AS mgids")`

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah I stand corrected -- the problem I was working around in my original response has been fixed in recent versions of Postgres, an improvement I wasn't aware of. Thanks for the tip; response updated.

Comment: Would anyone care to explain each line of the postgres solution shown above?  Specifically the join and group expression

Comment: You seem to know some SQL, so why don't you try to open a Rails console and enter the above query, appending `.to_sql` to the end so you can see what SQL is being generated. If the SQL doesn't make sense to you, then you should consider posting another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Category.includes(:photos).order(qty_download: :desc).reference(:photos)
```

Comment: This won't work, as there is no `total_downloads` column. (Also, you probably mean `references` instead of `reference`.)

Comment: A tiny bit of commenting on what it does and why it works would make the answer even more useful.